# Testing IO actions with Monadic QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, io, quickcheck

Can anyone give me a brief example of testing IO actions using Monadic QuickCheck?

Comment: Giving an example of what you would like to test, would make question better.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [Test.QuickCheck.Monadic](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.1.0.2/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Monadic.html) module lets you test monadic code, even things that run in `IO`.

A monadic property test is of type `PropertyM m a`, where `m` is the monad the test runs in and `a` is ultimately ignored.  In the case of `PropertyM IO a`, you convert the monadic test to a `Property` by using `monadicIO`; for all other monads, you use `monadic` instead (which takes a function to run the monad, something `IO` doesn't have).

In a monadic test, the value `return`ed out of the monad is ignored.  To check an expression, use `assert`; `assert`ing a false value will fail the test.  Use `run` to execute the code in the monad being tested.

There are other monadic actions at your disposal.  For example, `pick` will generate new test inputs out of a `Gen a`, and `pre` will check test preconditions.  These are useful if the test inputs or preconditions themselves depend on values computed via the monad being tested, in which case the normal way of generating inputs or checking precontions won't work.

Here's an example of testing some `IO` code: we check that after writing something to a temporary file, we can read that same data back.  For demonstration purposes, we'll impose the precondition that we write at least one byte to the file.  The two test properties do the same thing; one uses `pick` and `pre` unnecessarily while the other does not.

```
import System.Directory (removeFile)
import System.IO (hGetContents, hPutStr, hSeek, openBinaryTempFile, SeekMode (..))
import Test.QuickCheck (arbitrary, Property, quickCheck, (==>))
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic (assert, monadicIO, pick, pre, run)

-- Demonstrating pick and pre as well:
prop_writeThenRead :: Property
prop_writeThenRead = monadicIO $ do writtenData <- pick arbitrary
                                    pre $ not (null writtenData)
                                    readData <- run $ writeThenRead writtenData
                                    assert $ writtenData == readData

-- A more idiomatic way to write the above:
prop_writeThenRead2 :: [Char] -> Property
prop_writeThenRead2 writtenData = not (null writtenData) ==> monadicIO test
    where test = do readData <- run $ writeThenRead writtenData
                    assert $ writtenData == readData

writeThenRead :: [Char] -> IO [Char]
writeThenRead output = do (path, h) <- openBinaryTempFile "/tmp" "quickcheck.tmp"
                          removeFile path
                          hPutStr h output
                          hSeek h AbsoluteSeek 0
                          hGetContents h

main :: IO ()
main = do quickCheck prop_writeThenRead
          quickCheck prop_writeThenRead2
```

Answer (score 6):

The standard reference for testing monadic code is ["Testing Monadic Code with QuickCheck"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2831386_Testing_Monadic_Code_with_QuickCheck). It shows various ways of testing in the context of a monad such as IO.

But you should really consider posting a more concrete question about what it is that you would like to test.

Comment: Koen is apparently reorganizing his homepage. Try the following url instead:
[www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/QuickCheckST.ps](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/QuickCheckST.ps)

Comment: a link which works is http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=BC8CD4D1D79099509F359849B8764876?doi=10.1.1.19.9275&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: The link in the answer and those in the comments are all broken. I've updated the answer with the link that works today.