# Testing functions in Haskell that do IO

Tags: testing, haskell

Working through Real World Haskell right now. Here's a solution to a very early exercise in the book:

```
-- | 4) Counts the number of characters in a file
numCharactersInFile :: FilePath -> IO Int
numCharactersInFile fileName = do
    contents <- readFile fileName
    return (length contents)
```

My question is: How would you test this function? Is there a way to make a "mock" input instead of actually needing to interact with the file system to test it out? Haskell places such an emphasis on pure functions that I have to imagine that this is easy to do.

Comment: What then will remain to test after "mocking" filesystem? `length` function?

Comment: Haskell may place an emphasis on purity, but the IO monad is NOT pure.

Comment: If you did something more interesting than `length` on the contents of the file, you could easily test *that* function, which would be `String -> a` for some `a`.

Comment: @Dietrich Yes it is. Its `unsafePerformIO` that is impure ;)

Comment: @monadic: IO is impure even without `unsafePerformIO` or any other `unsafe*` function.

Comment: @Dietrich No. >>= and >> and return are pure.

Comment: See also [Testing IO actions with Monadic QuickCheck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259926/testing-io-actions-with-monadic-quickcheck)

Comment: @Derek You may be interested in trying out [hs-di](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hs-di) as it makes it possible to mock dependencies of functions that do IO. It's a dependency injection library for Haskell. A benefit I see of using a DI library is that it makes code testable with very little and much simpler modifications -- compared to some other approaches I see listed in the answers, e.g. introducing type classes or identifying and manually trying to factor out pure parts of a computation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Alexander Poluektov already pointed out, the code you are trying to test can easily be separated into a pure and an impure part.
Nevertheless I think it is good to know how to test such impure functions in haskell.
The usual approach to testing in haskell is to use [quickcheck](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck) and that's what I also tend to use for impure code.

Here is an example of how you might achieve what you are trying to do which gives you kind of a *mock* behavior *** :

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic(monadicIO,run,assert)
import System.Directory(removeFile,getTemporaryDirectory)
import System.IO
import Control.Exception(finally,bracket)

numCharactersInFile :: FilePath -> IO Int
numCharactersInFile fileName = do
    contents <- readFile fileName
    return (length contents)
```

Now provide an alternative function [(*Testing against a model)*](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/testing-and-quality-assurance.html):

```
numAlternative ::  FilePath -> IO Integer
numAlternative p = bracket (openFile p ReadMode) hClose hFileSize
```

Provide an Arbitrary instance for the test environment:

```
data TestFile = TestFile String deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
instance Arbitrary TestFile where
  arbitrary = do
    n <- choose (0,2000)
    testString <- vectorOf n $ elements ['a'..'z'] 
    return $ TestFile testString
```

Property testing against the model (using [quickcheck for monadic code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Monadic.html)):

```
prop_charsInFile (TestFile string) = 
  length string > 0 ==> monadicIO $ do
    (res,alternative) <- run $ createTmpFile string $
      \p h -> do
          alternative <- numAlternative p
          testRes <- numCharactersInFile p
          return (testRes,alternative)
    assert $ res == fromInteger alternative
```

And a little helper function:

```
createTmpFile :: String -> (FilePath -> Handle -> IO a) -> IO a
createTmpFile content func = do
      tempdir <- catch getTemporaryDirectory (\_ -> return ".")
      (tempfile, temph) <- openTempFile tempdir ""
      hPutStr temph content
      hFlush temph
      hClose temph
      finally (func tempfile temph) 
              (removeFile tempfile)
```

This will let quickCheck create some random files for you and test your implementation against a model function.

```
$ quickCheck prop_charsInFile 
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Of course you could also test some other properties depending on your usecase.

---

*** Note about the my usage of the term **mock behavior**:
The term *mock* in the object oriented sense is perhaps not the best here. But what is the intention behind a mock?
It let's you test code that needs access to a resource that usually is

- either not available at testing time
- or is not easily controllable and thus not easy to verify.

By shifting the responsibility of providing such a resource to quickcheck, it suddenly becomes feasible to provide an environment for the code under test that can be verified after a test run.
Martin Fowler describes this nicely in an [article about mocks](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) :
*"Mocks are ... objects pre-programmed with expectations which form a specification of the calls they are expected to receive."*
For the quickcheck setup I'd say that files generated as input are "pre-programmed" such that we know about their size (== expectation). And then they are verified against our specification (== property).

Comment: This doesn't act, speak, or talk like a mock.  A mock should not be touching the file system.  I do think the OP might need to introduce a typeclass to abstract the use of IO in order to use mock object, just as any other language does.  I.e in C++ virtual functions are required, in Java, interfaces are required to use mocking frameworks.

Comment: @user239558: good remark. I added a clarification to my usage of the term mock.

Answer (score 46):

You can make your code testable by using a type-class-constrained type variable instead of IO.

First, let's get the imports out of the way.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import qualified Prelude
import Prelude hiding(readFile)
import Control.Monad.State
```

The code we want to test:

```
class Monad m => FSMonad m where
    readFile :: FilePath -> m String

-- | 4) Counts the number of characters in a file
numCharactersInFile :: FSMonad m => FilePath -> m Int
numCharactersInFile fileName = do
    contents <- readFile fileName
    return (length contents)
```

Later, we can run it:

```
instance FSMonad IO where
    readFile = Prelude.readFile
```

And test it too:

```
data MockFS = SingleFile FilePath String

instance FSMonad (State MockFS) where 
               -- ^ Reader would be enough in this particular case though
    readFile pathRequested = do
        (SingleFile pathExisting contents) <- get
        if pathExisting == pathRequested
            then return contents
            else fail "file not found"


testNumCharactersInFile :: Bool
testNumCharactersInFile =
    evalState
        (numCharactersInFile "test.txt") 
        (SingleFile "test.txt" "hello world")
      == 11
```

This way your code under test needs very little modification.

Comment: This is the only correct approach IMO. It is unfortunate that these isn't a set of standard mockable typeclasses for this, along with standard mockability.

Comment: Agreed.  Best attempt at addressing a "real" mock.

Comment: This solution uses TypeSynonymInstances.  Is this frowned upon?

Comment: @Dave, that extension is only used in the testing code for brewity and you can easily avoid that by making a `newtype`.

Comment: I know I'm asking a noob question (and I'm a noob haskeller), but I've tried not to use the language extension and I wasn't able to get it working, could you share the code again please?

Comment: @Milad, I added the import section so the code is now self-contained. If you want to get rid of `FlexibleInstances`, you'd have to wrap `State MockFS` into a newtype.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've removed `FlexibleInstances`, and I have added the `newtype`,  but it doesn't compile -- see https://gist.github.com/miladhub/e039b38d1dcb24f4234da79d8780fe58

The error is:
`
testing.hs:20:18: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘StateMockFS’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘FSMonad’, namely ‘StateMockFS’
      In the instance declaration for ‘FSMonad StateMockFS’
   |
20 | instance FSMonad StateMockFS where 
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
`

Answer (score 9):

For that you will need to modify the function such that it becomes:

```
numCharactersInFile :: (FilePath -> IO String) -> FilePath -> IO Int
numCharactersInFile reader fileName = do
                         contents <- reader fileName
                         return (length contents)
```

Now you can pass any mock function that takes a file path and return IO string such as:

```
fakeFile :: FilePath -> IO String
fakeFile fileName = return "Fake content"
```

and pass this function to `numCharactersInFile`.

Comment: Replace `IO` with `Monad m => m` and it becomes Haskell-ish enough.

Answer (score 8):

The function consists from two parts: impure (reading part content as String) and pure (calculating the length of String).

The impure part cannot be "unit"-tested by definition. The pure part is just call to the library function (and of course you can test it if you want :) ).

So there is nothing to mock and nothing to unit-test in this example.

Put it another way. Consider you have an equal C++ or Java implementation (*): reading content and then calculating its length. What would you really want to mock and what would remain for testing afterwards?

---

(*) which is of course *not* the way you will do in C++ or Java, but that's offtopic.

Comment: I have downvoted because this is not an answer. This answer can be summarized to "you can't", which is not really true and thus not useful. Also, I fail to see what definition of unit-testing disallows testing of impure functions (they do it all the time in Java :D).

Comment: I agree and disagree with this post. The key insight is right -- test the pure part and impure parts separately. The "mock" of the results of a `readFile` is just a string -- precisely what you pass to `length` to begin with! My disagreement is just that one can of course unit-test `readFile` -- its just that when doing so, one of course should *not* mock it.

Comment: @sclv All in all, it depends on what definition of the "*unit*-testing" you use. I use one that prohibits touching functions that do IO things.

Comment: FWIW, the question as it stands does not contain the word 'unit'.

Comment: @steamer25: But the text that follows implied it: why would one want to mock something if s/he does (non-unit) testing?

Comment: @Alexander Poluekov: Maybe automated behavioral/functional testing? I.e., "Given a file that doesn't exist, the system should..."

Answer (score 6):

Based on my layman's understanding of Haskell, I've come to the following conclusions:

1. If a function makes use of the IO monad, mock testing is going to be impossible.  Avoid hard-coding the IO monad in your function.
2. Make a helper version of your function that takes in other functions that may do IO.  The result will look like this:

> ```
> numCharactersInFile' :: Monad m => (FilePath -> m String) -> FilePath -> m Int
> numCharactersInFile' f filePath = do
>     contents <- f filePath
>     return (length contents)
> ```

`numCharactersInFile'` is now testable with mocks!

```
mockFileSystem :: FilePath -> Identity String
mockFileSystem "fileName" = return "mock file contents"
```

Now you can verify that numCharactersInFile' returns the the expected results w/o IO:

```
18 == (runIdentity .  numCharactersInFile' mockFileSystem $ "fileName")
```

Finally, export a version of your original function signature for use with IO

```
numCharactersInFile :: IO Int
numCharactersInFile = NumCharactersInFile' readFile
```

So, at the end of the day, numCharactersInFile' is testable with mocks.  numCharactersInFile is just a variation of numCharactersInFile'.

Comment: FYI, this is a combination of Ankur's solution combined incorporating Rotsor's comment.