# Mocking IO Actions: getArgs and putStrLn

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, mocking, monads, hunit

I'm trying to test a small function (or rather, IO Action) that takes a command line argument and outputs it to the screen. My original (untestable) function is:

```
-- In Library.hs
module Library where

import System.Environment (getArgs)

run :: IO ()
run = do
  args <- getArgs
  putStrLn $ head args
```

After looking at [this answer about mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374754/1319998), I have come up with a way to mock `getArgs` and `putStrLn` by using a type class constrained type. So the above function becomes:

```
-- In Library.hs
module Library where

class Monad m => SystemMonad m where
  getArgs :: m [String]
  putStrLn :: String -> m ()

instance SystemMonad IO where
  getArgs = System.Environment.getArgs
  putStrLn = Prelude.putStrLn

run :: SystemMonad m => m ()
run = do
  args <- Library.getArgs
  Library.putStrLn $ head args
```

This `Library.`, `Prelude.` and `System.Environment.` are to avoid compiler complaints of `Ambigious Occurence`. My test file looks like the following.

```
-- In LibrarySpec.hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Library
import Test.Hspec
import Control.Monad.State

data MockArgsAndResult = MockArgsAndResult [String] String
  deriving(Eq, Show)

instance SystemMonad (State MockArgsAndResult) where 
    getArgs = do 
      MockArgsAndResult args _ <- get
      return args
    putStrLn string = do
      MockArgsAndResult args _ <- get
      put $ MockArgsAndResult args string
      return ()

main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
  describe "run" $ do
    it "passes the first command line argument to putStrLn" $ do
      (execState run (MockArgsAndResult ["first", "second"] "")) `shouldBe` (MockArgsAndResult ["first", "second"] "first")
```

I'm using a `State` monad that effectively contains 2 fields.

1. A list for the command line arguments where the mock `getArgs` reads from
2. A string that the mock `putStrLn` puts what was passed to it.

The above code works and seems to test what I want it to test. However, I'm wondering if there is some better / cleaner / more idiomatic way of testing this. For one thing, I'm using the same state to both put stuff into the test (my fake command line arguments), and then get stuff out of it (what was passed to `putStrLn`.

Is there a better way of doing what I'm doing? I'm more familiar with mocking in a Javascript environment, and my knowledge of Haskell is pretty basic (I arrived at the above solution by a fair bit of trial and error, rather than actual understanding)

Comment: I think your code is good / clean / idiomatic. The real questions is does this solve your problem? Is your "model" sufficient to accurately represent the actual "filesystem" you are modelling? If so, there is probably no need to overthink this. But, `putStrLn` should probably append its string arguement to the old string in the state, instead of ignoring the old string, if you really want to simulate `Prelude.putStrLn`.

Comment: @user2407038 Appending to the old string sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The better way is to avoid needing to provide mock versions of `getArgs` and `putStrLn` by separating out the heart of the computation into a pure function.

Consider this example:

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let n = length $ filter (\w -> length w < 5) args
  putStrLn $ "Number of small words: " ++ show n
```

One could say that the heart of the computation is counting the number of small words which is a pure function of type `[String] -> Int`. This suggest that we should refactor the program like this:

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let n = countSmallWords args
  putStrLn $ "Number of small words: " ++ show n

countSmallWords :: [String] -> Int
countSmallWords ws = ...
```

Now we just test `countSmallWords`, and this is easy because it is pure function.

Comment: Yes, separating out into pure functions seems good, but there would always be some IO actions (/ functions that return IO actions) left that would appear to need testing, at least that they are passed the result of the pure functions.

Comment: Come up with an example, and we can explore ways to organize it to make testing easier.

Comment: Er... The one in my original question, and the one in your answer seem like quite good examples! Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're requesting?

Comment: Come up with a more involved real-life example.