# Can I mock an interactive program using the state monad?

Tags: haskell, io, state, monads

Based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374754/1556475) I was inspired to try and make a program where the state monad could be swapped for the IO monad and it would still work. So far I came up with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.State

class Monad m => Interaction m where
  getInput :: m String
  produceOutput :: String -> m ()

instance Interaction IO where
  getInput = getLine
  produceOutput = putStrLn

instance Interaction (State String) where
  getInput = get
  produceOutput = put

interactiveProgram :: Interaction m => m ()
interactiveProgram = do
  name <- getInput
  produceOutput $ "Hey " ++ name
```

This works fine if I run it in GHCi, and I can also run `interactiveProgram` like so: `runState interactiveProgram "Jeff"`. It gets messy when I add extra `getInput` calls though:

```
interactiveProgram :: Interaction m => m ()
interactiveProgram = do
  name <- getInput
  name2 <- getInput
  produceOutput $ "Hey " ++ name ++ " and " ++ name2
```

In the case of the IO monad, the user is prompted for another name and the output is something like "Hey Jeff and Geoff". But in the state monad example, I have no way to provide that second name. Instead I get `((),"Hey Jeff and Jeff)` (the provided name repeated twice).

Is it possible to come up with an implementation for the `State String` instance that allows arbitrarily many "inputs" that get fed to the `getInput` calls?

Comment: You could certainly change the implementation of `getInput` so that it modifies the state in some way after the `get`. But it would have to be in some determinate, fixed way. You can't make a program truly interactive without involving `IO`.

Comment: Yeah, determinate and fixed way is what I am going for. Ideally I'd like to be able to run the program with a fixed set of inputs via `runState` and then when it needs to be interactive, just run it in the IO monad.

Comment: The similarities between the IO and State monads are striking. This allows to mimick and sequence user interactions in any language using pure functions. If you're curious about a JavaScript implementation, you can find it [here](https://faustinelli.wordpress.com/2014/06/01/state-monad-goes-to-js-town-and-starts-swinging/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two lists of strings instead. One for the inputs, one for the outputs.

```
instance Interaction (State ([String],[String])) where
  getInput = do
     (x:xs,o) <- get
     put (xs,o)
     return x
  produceOutput x = do
     (i,o) <- get
     put (i,x:o)
```

This assumes that the initial state contains a large enough list of input strings. It that's too short, `getInput` will crash.

Further, this only models inputs which are known at startup. It does not model an interactive user who can see the outputs and answers accordingly.

Finally, a properly interactive program can be modeled by the recursive type

```
data IOpure a 
  = Return a
  | Output String (IOpure a)
  | Input (String -> IOpure a)
  deriving Functor

instance Applicative IOpure where
   pure = Return
   (<*>) = ap

instance Monad IOpure where
   Return x >>= f = f x
   Output s io >>= f = Output s (io >>= f)
   Input k >>= f = Input (\s -> k s >>= f)

instance Interaction IOpure where
  getInput = Input Return
  produceOutput x = Output x (Return ())
```

To run this using actual IO, you can use

```
runIOpure :: IOpure a -> IO a
runIOpure (Return x)    = return x
runIOpure (Output x io) = putStrLn x >> runIOpure io
runIOpure (Input k)     = getLine >>= runIOpure . k
```

Another example: this models a user which, when prompted for an input, echoes the last output (or "no output", at the very beginning). This is just one possible way of consuming an `IOpure a` value.

```
echoingUser :: IOpure a -> a
echoingUser = go "no output"
   where
   go _ (Return x)    = x
   go _ (Output o io) = go o io
   go o (Input k)     = go o (k o)
```

You could try using `echoingUser` on

```
interactiveProgram :: Interaction m => m (String, String)
interactiveProgram = do
  produceOutput "Jeff"
  name <- getInput
  produceOutput "Bob"
  name2 <- getInput
  return (name, name2)
```

Try the [ideone example](https://ideone.com/ImMQCv) with all the code above.

Comment: I started playing around with this idea just as you suggested it! Thanks!

Comment: @CameronBall I changed it to use two lists, because it looks better to me. Otherwise, outputs are used for the next inputs, which feels wrong (IMO).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last edit a bit? It's not so clear how I would implement and run that.

Comment: @CameronBall I added a small real-IO interpreter.

Comment: Cool! Getting off topic I guess... But I don't really get what writing interpreters gives me. In your example, if I wanted to run my IOpure without real IO, I would have to write something like `runIOpureState :: IOpure a -> State String a` - how is that better than having a typeclass which `State String` implements?

Comment: Further... writing the `Interaction` instances in terms of `IOpure` makes my `interactiveProgram` function not compile, since there's no monad instance for `IOpure`. But if the implementation is in the typeclass instance (rather than some `runIOpure` function), I get the monad instance for free for things like `IO` and `State`. I see a lot of people use this interpreter style though, so what am I missing that makes it so useful?

Comment: @CameronBall We can't use `State String` for that, since it models true interaction, where the user can see the outputs and provide inputs accordingly. There was a typo in the instance, which should have been for `IOpure` instead. There is no obvious way to write a truly general `runIOpure` I can see. I can give you one example of a less general one.

Comment: I get that a specific implementation of `runIOpure` is require to run an `IOpure` in to a specific monad, that makes sense. What I don't understand is why it's good to put the implementation of that in to a specific `runIOpure` function vs just putting the implementation directly in the instance implementation. More precisely, why would I prefer to write a `runIOpure` function when I can just put the implementation directly  in to the `IO` instance of `Interaction`?

Comment: @CameronBall An IO action can do anything, IOpure can only use the specific operations `Output` and `Input` -- no disk/network access, mutable variables, etc. But that's not necessarily "good". I only wanted to show another way to implement `Interaction`, without claiming it's better or worse. Ultimately, it depends on your goals.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for the comprehensive answers :)