# Haskell Functional Tests against a JSON API

Tags: unit-testing, testing, haskell

I'm writing a Haskell JSON API, and I'd like to write some tests. The thing is really IO heavy, so I think it makes the most sense to write some functional tests: (Add a Foo, see if /foos/ returns it), etc.

I've read about QuickCheck of course, but it seems to focus on testing pure code.

How should I write/run functional tests that need to test an API? If it matters, I'm using [Scotty/WAI](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.0.1). Although an example would be great, a good couple links and some advice would be fine.

Comment: Related question: What's the simplest HTTP client library? As in, handles PUT/DELETE, easy, sets the Content-Length header for you?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your use-case that you're writing another JSON library rather than using an existing one?

Comment: Why is it IO heavy? Are you sure that it can't be refactored so that more of it is pure?

Comment: I'm not writing another JSON library. I'm writing a web application that produces and consumes JSON objects.

Comment: It is IO heavy because it's a web application :) It primarily grabs some data from a request, updates or reads a database, and spits something back out. You're right, I could test the pure bits, but most of my errors are in the IO steps, so I thought a functional test would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used it, but QuickCheck actually *does* support testing monadic code. Look at [Testing IO actions with Monadic QuickCheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259926/testing-io-actions-with-monadic-quickcheck) for more information. If your api has some invariants that are easy to express, this is probably a good way to test it. (In my experience with pure code, QuickCheck covers more corner cases than I can think of, which makes it very useful.)

Comment: I got it working similarly to this: https://gist.github.com/967505, but it hits the api call 100x, which seems like overkill. Any way to dial that down? Should I?

Comment: You can use something like `quickCheckWith stdArgs { maxSuccess = 25 } someProp` to run a test with 25 arguments instead of 100.

Answer (score 1):

I have a half-baked(yet almost done) blog entry to explain how to test wai application with hspec. Hope it helps!

https://github.com/fujimura/wai-hspec-example/blob/master/testing-wai-app-with-hspec.md
https://github.com/fujimura/wai-hspec-example